# ImageView can not be resized using the layout weight

Tags: android, imageview, android-layout-weight

I want to divide my screen into 3 vertically equal parts and add an ImageView to the top part. When I add the image, the parts won't be equal.

It can not be changed using layout weight.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
android:paddingLeft="30dp"
android:paddingRight="30dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo1"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you are using `layout_weight`, then change your `layout_height` to this `android:layout_height="0dp"`

Comment: and also add to your ImageView   android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `android:layout_height="0dp"` in all **LinearLayout** like :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"  
    android:layout_weight="1">

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ff0000">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#00ff00">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#0000ff">

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]